# How to close pop-up on successful sign-in

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication, popupwindow

My index page contains a sign-in link which pops up the login html within a 400x380 window. This login form has an action of login.php when submitted.

If login.php is successful, you're logged in but within the pop-up window. Instead, I want to close this pop-up on successful sign-up, and have the user reverted to the original index page but signed in now.

My index page uses the following code for the pop-up window:

```
<li><a onclick="popupCenter('http://taskbasket.net/gallery/login.html', 'myPop1',400,380);" href="javascript:void(0);">Sign In</a></li>
```

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Once you've authorized your user the next step should be to take over the current window with your application by use the "_self" argument to window.open().  So, for example, in your login.php code you should have a call like window.open('myMainApp.html?authCodeHere=secretCode', '_self', "", false);   The authorization parameter is just an example, since you could be setting a cookie or a path to the legit page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on your login.php

```
echo '<script>if (window.opener){window.opener.location.href="PUT URL TO PAGE HERE"; window.close();}</script>';
```

And edit your HTML

```
<li><a onclick="popupCenter('http://taskbasket.net/gallery/login.html', 'myPop1',400,380);" href="javascript:void(0);">Sign In</a></li>
```

To

```
  <li><a onclick="openLoginWindow()" href="javascript:void(0);">Sign In</a></li>
```

JavaScript:

```
function openLoginWindow()
{  
    myPop1 = popupCenter('http://taskbasket.net/gallery/login.html', 'myPop1',400,380);
}
```

This script lets the pop up access the parent and call for a reload (with the user now logged in) and as final step is closes itself.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if I was suppose to change "myPop1" to something in particular?? I left it as is, and the script didn't close the pop-up, but simply reloaded the index page *within* the popup, after it loaded the first time. I need the popup closed, and then the parent window refreshed.

Comment: Can you post your popupCenter code for me? This should've worked.

Comment: <script>
function popupCenter(url, title, w, h) {
  var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
  var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
  return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
} 
</script>

Comment: And the rest is posted in my original message. Thank you

Comment: According to the specs this should reload the parent window and close the child.

Comment: You can try it yourself. The website is: http://taskbasket.net/gallery/index.php     Click "Sign In" in the top right corner, and use the username:    extra.stuff@mail.com   and password    ccc       . what does it do for you?

Comment: `window.open` needs to be saved to a variable. Then this will work.

Comment: Your updated solution works like an absolute charm! Thank you, I really appreciate it

Comment: @Nova glad to be of service. Good luck developing your site.